How to Accurately Retrieve Camera's Linear and Angular Velocity per Frame in Blender?
Hello Blender community,
I am a complete beginner with Blender, working on generating synthetic data for a computer vision project that requires the linear and angular velocities of a camera for each frame it renders. My scene is already set up with objects and a camera that follows a predefined path.
To track the camera’s movement, I've attempted to use bpy.data.objects['Camera'].location.copy() in the Python console to fetch the camera's position in order to compute the linear velocity (assuming velocity = change in position/change in time, with time = 1/FPS). However, this method returns the same position for every frame, which doesn’t seem correct.
Could someone advise me on what I might be doing wrong? How can I ensure Blender updates the frame and fetches the new position of the camera for each frame in my script? Additionally, any tips on how to calculate the angular velocity would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
